# Is it possible to import Outlook tasks to Google Calendar?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, google-calendar

I successful migrated Outlook's contacts  into Gmail contacts, but for some reason I'm not able to import my Outlook's Task's CSV   into Google Calendar.

Any ideas?

Comment: Related (not a duplicate): [Free calendar sync tool for synchronizing Outlook Calendar with with Google](http://superuser.com/questions/561660/free-calendar-sync-tool-for-synchronizing-outlook-calendar-with-with-google)

Comment: Are you trying to copy the Calendar or the Tasks? I wouldn't expect that you could copy Outlook Tasks to Google Calendar as they are different data types.

Answer (score 1):

The process from Google detailing event **importation** from iCal or CSV formats [is shown here](http://support.google.com/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=37118), and is fairly simple - you just need to export your calendar from Outlook in an appropriate format, and import it into your Google account.  iCal is the preferred format, as CSV formats might not work correctly with recurring events.  The process to **export** your calendar in iCal format [is outlined in this article](http://support.google.com/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=83126).

---

Likewise, you might also want to see this Microsoft KB article: [Transfer calendars between Outlook and Google Calendar](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/outlook-help/transfer-calendars-between-outlook-and-google-calendar-HA010167495.aspx), which outlines the process from Microsoft's perspective:

> By using Microsoft Office Outlook 2007, you can import and export calendars from Google Calendar as Calendar Snapshots in the iCalendar format. This functionality enables you to transfer calendars between Outlook and Google Calendar.

Comment: many thanks to all!
yes, I'm trying to migrate my outlook tasks to google calendar, just because this way was recommended by http://www.ehow.com/how_5849305_export-ms-outlook-google-calendars.html.
in fact, I just want to copy my tasks to google; I didn't see any manual for import google tasks.

Comment: @Vitaly did my answer help solve your question?  If so, could you mark it as the correct answer?  (it's bad practice to leave questions un-answered)  Alternatively, if you did find the solution in a different manner, you are free to post it as an answer to your own question.

Comment: sorry, no. I asked to Tasks migration, not calendar. thank you anyway.

Comment: The link you posted in the comment outlines how to do this.